# Excel VBA Loop with Excel Solver with copying cell value depending on certain different cell value

Tags: vba, excel, loops, solver

I am new with VBA and trying to implement an Excel Solver Loop. Until now I did not find a solution for my specific problem so I am hoping I can get some help here.

So what I am exactly doing is the following:

1. Using Solver to minimize an objective cell (In this case B16)
2. Changing cell value (C2), as many times as needed, until solver solution changes (value gets bigger or smaller depending in Value of E8 what can be 1 or 0)
3. Copying this cell value in a predefined cell (F8 or G8, depending on
   Value of E8, what can be 1 or 0)
4. Changing Cell Value (C2) to its start value at the beginning
5. Switch to next cell below (C3) and change cell value until solution changes
6. Copying this cell value in a predefined cell (F9 or G9, depending on
   Value of E9, what can be 1 or 0)

So until step 4 it works perfectly, but only for that one cell. I want to have the possibility now to go down cell by cell. Therefor I tried it by implementing an i for counting the rows but always got default messages.

So here my code:

```
Sub Makro6()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("C2")

If Range("E8").Value = 1 Then

Do
    For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
    Next cell

    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$16", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$8:$E$9", _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$16", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$8:$E$9", _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverSolve True

Loop Until Range("E8").Value = 0

   'Copying cell Value, when Solver solution switched in certain cell depending if it before was 1 or 0
   Range("C2").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Range("F8").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

   'Copying start value back into cell after solver loop
   Range("B2").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Range("C2").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

Else

Do
    For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = cell.Value - 1
    Next cell

    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$16", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$8:$E$9", _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$16", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$8:$E$9", _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverSolve True

Loop Until Range("E8").Value = 1

   'Copying cell Value, when Solver solution switched in certain cell depending if it before was 1 or 0
   Range("C2").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Range("G8").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

   'Copying start value back into cell after solver loop
   Range("B2").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Range("C2").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "default messages"?

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to implement the i, so that cells can change. I tried to implement it into the Range: Set rng = Range(i, 3), but it tells me default 1004, that the method for the object global failed

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't quite answer my question. Are you saying that you want to complete steps 1-3 for C2 and then repeat for C3 and so on? If so, where do the results of successive iterations go?

Comment: Yes I want to complete steps 1-3 for C2 and then go further to C3. The Value in C2 (which should be the turning point when the excel solver solution changes) should be filled in automatically in F8, if E8 was 1 before, and in G8 if E8 was 0. Then I want to repeat everything with C3, put the result in F9 or G9 and so on...did this explanation helped you to understand my problem? :)

Comment: Yes, I think so. I will have a look shortly if nobody else has done so in the meantime. One last thing though - are you just doing C2 and C3 or more cells?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) yes in the end I want to do it with a bigger number of cells, at the moment I just try it with a small model to later extend it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, give this a whirl. It should work for C2 and C3 but can be extended as far as you like by changing the line defining rng

```
Sub Makro6()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("C2:C3")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Offset(6, 2).Value = 1 Then
        Do
            cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
            SolverOk SetCell:="$B$16", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$8:$E$9", _
            Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
            SolverOk SetCell:="$B$16", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$8:$E$9", _
            Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
            SolverSolve True
        Loop Until cell.Offset(6, 2).Value = 0
            'Copying cell Value, when Solver solution switched in certain cell depending if it before was 1 or 0
            cell.Copy cell.Offset(6, 3)
            'Copying start value back into cell after solver loop
            cell.Offset(, -1).Copy cell
    Else
        Do
           cell.Value = cell.Value - 1
           SolverOk SetCell:="$B$16", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$8:$E$9", _
           Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
           SolverOk SetCell:="$B$16", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$C$8:$E$9", _
           Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
           SolverSolve True
        Loop Until cell.Offset(6, 2).Value = 1
            'Copying cell Value, when Solver solution switched in certain cell depending if it before was 1 or 0
            cell.Copy cell.Offset(6, 4)
            'Copying start value back into cell after solver loop
            cell.Offset(, -1).Copy cell
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey that works perfectly! Just had to copy the solver another time after the "End If" to make sure that the solver solution is the same as in the beginning, but then it makes exactly what I want! Thank you, you saved my whole day of trying, freaking out and searching information about it=)

Comment: I have just one more question again: is it possible to use the cell.offset(,-1).copy cell but just to copy the cell value? So if I have a formula in the other cell this formula does not work...I just found this possibility with pastespecial, but I am hoping it is possible to make it more easily?

Comment: You can use copy and then pastespecial values (the latter on a new line) or replace `cell.Offset(, -1).Copy cell` with `cell.value=cell.Offset(, -1).value`

Comment: Super! Sometimes things are so easy, but you don't find a solution :D Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select
```

Remember, it's always (Row, Column), so if you are in cell C3, the code above will move to C4.  If you are in cell C3 and you want to move to D3, you would do it like this.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select
```